# How is the classification of groups extensions by $H^2$ related to Yoneda Ext?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, extension

It is well-known that  group extensions
$$1\to A \to H \to G \to 1$$
where $A$ is abelian with a $G$-action such that the conjugation action of $G$ on $A$ agree with this fixed action are classified by the group cohomology $H^2(G,A)=\text{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}^2(\mathbb{Z},A)$.

On the other hand, it is also well known that $\text{Ext}$ groups in abelian categories classify extensions, so $\text{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}^2(\mathbb{Z},A)$ also classifies two-step extensions
$$0\to A \to B \to C \to \mathbb{Z}\to 0$$
in the category of $G$-modules.

Hence we have two sets that are both in bijection with $\text{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}^2(\mathbb{Z},A)$. My question is:

> Is there a direct way (i.e. not going through cohomology) to describe the bijection between group extensions of $G$ by $A$ with a given conjugation action and two-step extensions of $\mathbb{Z}$ by $A$ in the category of $G$-modules?

**Idea:** The short exact sequence
$$0\to I_G \to \mathbb{Z}[G] \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$
induces an isomorphism $\text{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}^1(I_G,A) \overset{\sim}{\to} \text{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}^2(\mathbb{Z},A)$
where $I_G$ is the augmentation ideal. Explicitly, it sends an extension $0\to A \to B \to I_G \to 0$ to $0\to A \to B \to \mathbb{Z}[G] \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$. Hence it is enough to describe a bijection between group extensions of $G$ by $A$ with a given conjugation action and extensions of $I_G$ by $A$ in the category of $G$-modules. This might be an easier reformulation since now we have just one-step extensions on both sides.

**Note:** I am aware of [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118044/an-isomorphism-between-different-exts-coming-from-group-cohomology), but that one is only about the case where $G$ is abelian.

Comment: You can find a proof along these lines done more generally for categories in prop 7.3 of Peter Webb https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~webb/Publications/CategoryAlgebras.pdf. He says this approach was first done for groups by Gruenberg in 10.5 of https://bookstore.ams.org/cbms-25

Comment: The group extension gives a 2-cocyle for the bar resolution and the 2-cocyle an extension of length 2 by the construction described in the first diagram in 5.14 in vol. 2 of @Dave Benson's group cohomology book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460471/how-is-the-classification-of-groups-extensions-by-h2-related-to-yoneda-ext#comment1194192_460471) above, Gruenberg gave a direct bijection between $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathbb ZG}(I_G,A)$ and group extensions $1\to A\to H\to G\to 1$.  The details can be found in either 10.5 of Relation Modules of Finite Groups by K. W. Gruenberg or the paper [An Introduction to the Representations and Cohomology of Categories](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Ewebb/Publications/CategoryAlgebras.pdf) of Webb I linked above (done there in the more general setting of categories).

The rough idea is given an extension $0\to A\to E\to I_G\to 0$ for $\mathbb ZG$-modules, we have an exact sequence of groups $1\to A\to E\rtimes G\to I_G\rtimes G\to 1$.  But we have a derivation $d\colon G\to I_G$ given by $d(g)=g-1$, and this gives a splitting $G\to I_G\rtimes G$ given by $g\mapsto (d(g),g)=(g-1,g)$.  Thus we can form a pullback diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
1 @>>> A @>>> H @>>> G @>>> 1 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
1 @>>> A @>>> E \rtimes G @>>> I_G \rtimes G @>>> 1
\end{CD}$$
to get our desired extension.

Conversely, given a group extension $1\to A\to H\to G\to 1$, note that $\mathbb ZH\cdot I_A$ is the kernel of the projection $\mathbb ZH\to \mathbb ZG$.   We can form the exact sequence of $\mathbb ZH$-modules $0\to \mathbb ZH\cdot I_A\to I_H\to I_G\to 0$ which yields the exact sequence of $\mathbb ZG$-modules
$0\to \mathbb ZH\cdot I_A/(\mathbb ZH\cdot I_A)\cdot  I_H\to I_H/ (\mathbb ZH\cdot I_A)\cdot  I_H\to I_G\to 0$.

One can then show that  $\mathbb ZH\cdot I_A/(\mathbb ZH\cdot I_A)\cdot I_H\cong A$ as a $\mathbb ZH$-module via $a\mapsto a-1+(\mathbb ZH\cdot I_A)\cdot I_H$.  These two operations can be checked to be inverse.  I refer you to the sources in my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460471/how-is-the-classification-of-groups-extensions-by-h2-related-to-yoneda-ext#comment1194192_460471) for details.

Comment: @LSpice,  thanks for fixing my diagram.  I had no idea how to use commutative diagrams in MO.

Answer (score 8):

I can tell you what to do in one direction; then the problem is to prove that this is well defined and bijective. Suppose you're given an element of $\operatorname{\rm Ext}^2_{\mathbb{Z}G}(\mathbb{Z},A)$ as $1\to A\to B \to C \to\mathbb{Z} \to 0$. Then we can look at the matrices of the form $\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & * & ? \\ 0 & X & * \\ 0&0&A \end{matrix}\right)$ where the extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ by $X$ is $C$ and the extension of $X$ by $A$ is $B$. Then the obstruction to this element of $\operatorname{\rm Ext}^2$ being zero is whether we can fill in the question marks in a consistent way. If, instead, we fill in the question mark in all possible ways, the values of the question mark form a copy of $A$, and the group $H$ of all matrices of this form sits in an exact sequence $1\to A \to H \to G \to 1$. This gives the correspondence, but the details of the proof would take some writing out. Maybe the best proof is to go via cocycles in the bar resolution, but I haven't tried to write it out in this fashion. But there's probably also a more straightforward proof...

By the way, I prefer to write $\mathbb{Z}G$ for the (cocommutative) group algebra and $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ for the (commutative) coordinate algebra. If $G$ is a finite group (scheme) these are dual Hopf algebras. This is more in line with algebraic geometry notation. But this is more of a rant than part of an answer, so my apologies.

**Edit** (18 Dec) Since the original poster seems not to be comfortable with my telegraphic style, let me spell out in great detail what I mean. The first observation is that since $\operatorname{Ext}^2_{\mathbb{Z}}=0$, we can form an abelian group $U$ with a filtration $U=U_0\geqslant U_1\geqslant U_2 \geqslant U_3=0$, so that $U_0/U_1\cong\mathbb{Z}$, $U_0/U_2\cong C$, $U_1/U_3\cong B$ and $U_2/U_3\cong A$, and so that these identifications are compatible in the obvious sense. Now consider the group $H$ consisting of the abelian group automorphisms $h$ of $U$ that preserve the filtration, and with the following properties.

1. The action of $h$ on $U_0/U_1$ is trivial.
2. The action of $h$ on $U_0/U_2$ agrees with the action of an element $g\in G$ on $C$.
3. The action of $h$ on $U_1/U_3$ agrees with the action of the same element $g\in G$ on $B$.
4. The action of $h$ on $U_2/U_3$ agrees with the action of the same element $g\in G$ on $A$.

Then there is a natural map from $H$ to $G$ sending $h$ to the $g$ named above. The kernel is the set of automorphisms of the form (identity plus $\alpha$), where $\alpha$ is an endomorphism with kernel containing $U_1$ and image contained in $U_2$. These are determined by what they do to $1\in \mathbb{Z}\cong U_0/U_1$, and so they form an abelian normal subgroup isomorphic to $A$.

The group structure is, of course, composition of automorphisms.

I hope this explanation is clearer.

Comment: I seem to have written this with right modules; transpose the matrices for left modules.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your matrix represents. Are the entries of the matrix $G$-modules?

Comment: This is shorthand for a module with a filtration with three filtered quotients. The top one is $\mathbb{Z}$, the top two form $C$, the the bottom two form $B$ and the bottom one is $A$.

Comment: I see, so by "fill in the question marks in a consistent way" I assume that you mean "find such a module with a three-step filtration". What do you mean then by "instead, we fill in the question mark in all possible ways"? And what is the group structure on such matrices?